# How to add noindex tag to certain media categories in Xenforo

Tags: media, xenforo, noindex

I'm trying to exclude from search certain media gallery categories in Xenforo but it doesn't works.

I add the following code in xfmg_media_view template.

```php
<xf:if is="{$media.category_id} == 1">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</xf:if>
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: I don't have media gallery, but I do have resource manager and that looks correct to me

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct conditional

```
<xf:if is="{$xf_mg_media_item.category_id} == 1">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
</xf:if>
```